# Joomla custom user extension

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm writing a Joomla 1.5 extension for an advanced frontend user interface.
Now I have to add a function so the users can upload a picture in the frontend and it will be added to their account.

Is there a standard Joomla picture upload available or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this is my code: (and some more I can not paste everything in here)

```
function deleteLogo($logo)
{

    // define path to file to delete
    $filePath =  'images/stories/members/' . $logo;
    $imagePath =  'images/stories/members/image/' . $image;

    // check if files exists
    $fileExists = JFile::exists($filePath);
    $imageExists = JFile::exists($imagePath);
    if($fileExists)
    {
        // attempt to delete file
        $fileDeleted = JFile::delete($filePath);
    }   

    if($imageExists)
    {
        // attempt to delete file
        $fileDeleted = JFile::delete($imagePath);
    }   
}

function saveLogo($files, $data)
{   
    $uploadFile = JRequest::getVar('logo', null, 'FILES', 'ARRAY');
    $uploadImage = JRequest::getVar('image', null, 'FILES', 'ARRAY');

    $save = true;
    $saveImage = true;

    if (!is_array($uploadFile)) {
        // @todo handle no upload present
        $save = false;
    }

    if ($uploadFile['error'] || $uploadFile['size'] < 1) {
        // @todo handle upload error
        $save = false;
    }

    if (!is_uploaded_file($uploadFile['tmp_name'])) {
        // @todo handle potential malicious attack
        $save = false;
    }

    if (!is_array($uploadImage)) {
        // @todo handle no upload present
        $saveImage = false;
    }

    if ($uploadImage['error'] || $uploadImage['size'] < 1) {
        // @todo handle upload error
        $saveImage = false;
    }

    if (!is_uploaded_file($uploadImage['tmp_name'])) {
        // @todo handle potential malicious attack
        $saveImage = false;
    }

    // Prepare the temporary destination path
    //$config = & JFactory::getConfig();
    //$fileDestination = $config->getValue('config.tmp_path'). DS . JFile::getName($uploadFile['tmp_name']);

    // Move uploaded file

    if($save)
    {
        $this->deleteLogo($data['oldLogo']);
        $fileDestination = 'images/stories/members/' . $data['id'] . '-' . $uploadFile['name'];
        $uploaded = JFile::upload($uploadFile['tmp_name'], $fileDestination);
    }

    if($saveImage)
    {
        $this->deleteLogo($data['oldImage']);
        $fileDestination = 'images/stories/members/image/' .  $data['id'] . '-' . $uploadImage['name'];
        $uploadedImage = JFile::upload($uploadImage['tmp_name'], $fileDestination);
    }
}
```